# CDI injection not done in base class for jax-rs controller

Tags: jax-rs, jboss7.x, cdi, jboss-weld

I'm struggling with CDI and class inheritence.
I've a JAX-RS controller declared as :

```
@Path("/share")
public class ControllerShare extends BaseController {
    @Inject
    private ServiceShare serviceShare;

    @PostConstruct
    private void verifInit() throws ExceptionTechnique {
        log.warn("Checking CDI injection");
        if (serviceShare == null) {
            log.error("serviceAccount not initialized. Check your EJB configuration");
            throw new ExceptionTechnique("serviceShare not initialized. Check your EJB configuration.");
        }
    }
...
}
```

This controller extends a base controller declared as :

```
public abstract class BaseController {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerShare.class);

    @Context protected HttpServletRequest request;
    @Inject private ControlerSession ctrlSession;

    public BaseController() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void verifInit() throws ExceptionTechnique {
        log.warn("Checking CDI injection");
        if (ctrlSession == null) {
            log.error("controllerSession not initialized. Check your CDI configuration");
            throw new ExceptionTechnique("serviceAccount not initialized. Check your CDI configuration.");
        }
    }
...
}
```

The problem is that injection is correctly done in ControllerShare (I correctly see "Checking CDI injection"), but is not done in the BaseController class (ctrlSession is null).
I try @Named and others combination without success. Injection is just done in ControllerShare and not in BaseController.

**EDIT:**
One more thing : curiously the @Context is working fine. My request is set and the value is correct.

Thank's for any explanation and solution.

Comment: Quite confusing, you talk as if there are two objects instead of one, and never come out and say whether you see both @PostContruct methods.  AIUI The only valid question to ask here is:

  Is the ctrlSession field in your instance null or non-null?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this should work according to

http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/inheritance.html

> 4.2. Inheritance of member-level metadata
>
> Suppose a class X is extended directly or indirectly by the bean class of a managed bean or session bean Y.
>
> - If X declares an injected field x then Y inherits x.

On a side note: `@PostConstruct` however is not inherited if you specify it anew. Therefore, in your sub-class your method must be named differently to have both initializers executed.

> - If X declares an initializer, non-static observer, @PostConstruct or @PreDestroy method x() then Y inherits x() if and only if neither Y nor any intermediate class that is a subclass of X and a superclass of Y overrides the method x().

Comment: I try on the BaseController and it does nothing. In the ControllerShare I got this message : Specializing bean must extend another bean:  Managed Bean [class clouderial.saas.commons.web.controlers.ControlerShare] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

Comment: Is there a valid producer for `ControlerSession` anyway?

Comment: ControlerSession don't need Producer because it's well recognized as a bean. @ Inject works great elsewhere for this bean

Comment: 'Therefore, in your sub-class your method must be named differently to have both initializers executed.' In the BaseController @ PostConstruct is never call, whatever it is named.

Comment: The main problem is that BaseController is not a managed bean.

Comment: I have reconstructed the setup in glassfish 3.1.2 and could not reproduce your problem. Even an abstract base class worked with injection. I also verified that the initializer methods are both called. Therefore I assume that either the jax rs part causes this problem or your implementation of CDI behaves differently. I guess the latter is more likely. So you could throw your stuff to another app server.

Comment: Thank's for all. Like you I guess it is related to JAX-RS because it works with other (Non JAX-RS) classes.

Comment: Ok, then maybe make the jax rs controller a facade delegating the calls to your service, that  you can inject into your jax rs facade. I hope that helped a bit at least.